# How to create sequence number based on total value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Would like to seek some advice how to create a sequence number field based on a total value/count?

Any possible way I can generate the result without using while loop? Thanks!

| CustID | EmpID | TotalCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 1001 | 3 |
| 50 | 1002 | 5 |

Expected result:

| SeqNo | CustID | EmpID | TotalCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **40** | 40 | 1001 | 3 |
| **41** | 40 | 1001 | 3 |
| **42** | 40 | 1001 | 3 |
| **50** | 50 | 1002 | 5 |
| **51** | 50 | 1002 | 5 |
| **52** | 50 | 1002 | 5 |
| **53** | 50 | 1002 | 5 |
| **54** | 50 | 1002 | 5 |

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? `a sequence number field based on a total value/count` is unclear. If you want to number rows for display/reporting, use ROW_NUMBER. If you want to calculate ID values based on the existing values (MAX+1) *don't do that* - it guarantees duplicates and ghost entries. All it takes is deleting a record to reproduce an ID value. The new record will end up related to any rows that were related to the old row. Why not use SQL Server's SEQUENCE or IDENTITY?

Comment: Due to some data file requirement, i need to generate data as above. The Seq_No will act as a "dummy ID" for CustID, which is based on its total count.

Comment: In the 40s above, the first in the sequence is 41, whereas the first in the sequence of the 50s is 50. Should the first record be custID + 0, custID + 1, or something else?

Comment: @seanb, sorry..it always start with first record ID..amended the table..

Comment: The results you posted have nothing to do with generating a sequence. You're trying to *repeat rows* based on a field value

Comment: Please add info on what to do  if `TotalCount` is more than 10 ...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion is to use a 'numbers' table and cross-join them to create the appropriate number of rows.

A simple numbers table is

```
CREATE TABLE #n (n int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO #n (n) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
```

A better approach to the numbers table (indeed, a similar overall approach as this answer) can be found in [How to pivot column data into a row where a maximum qty total cannot be exceeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675665/how-to-pivot-column-data-into-a-row-where-a-maximum-qty-total-cannot-be-exceeded/64679401#64679401)

Now, doing a cross join fundamentally 'multiplies' across the two tables. The main thing is to limit the number from the numbers table to the TotalCount.

```
SELECT    MyTable.CustID + n.n AS SeqNum, MyTable.CustID, MyTable.EmpID, MyTable.TotalCount
FROM      MyTable
          CROSS JOIN #n AS n
WHERE     n.n < TotalCount
```

You can also do it with an inner join and move the where clause to be part of the join itself.

```
SELECT    MyTable.CustID + n.n AS SeqNum, MyTable.CustID, MyTable.EmpID, MyTable.TotalCount
FROM      MyTable
          INNER JOIN #n AS n ON n.n < TotalCount
```

Edit: Note that SeqNum is not necessarily unique in the above - similar to @Luuk's comment/question regarding what happens when TotalCount is over 10. Also added added INNER JOIN version.

Comment: Thanks! I will use your method for simpler way. For the total count, i will add in some in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to solve such problems is to use [a `Numbers` table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/) - a table with just incrementing numbers from 1 to whatever limit you want. This table is so useful it's a good idea to have one in every database. Copying from the linked article:

```
DECLARE @UpperBound INT = 1000000;

;WITH cteN(Number) AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) - 1
  FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
)
SELECT [Number] INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM cteN WHERE [Number] <= @UpperBound;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_Number ON dbo.Numbers([Number]);
```

One you have such a table, generating repeating rows can be done with a CROSS JOIN :

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable CROSS join Numbers 
WHERE  TotalCount < Numbers.Number
```

To add the sequence number you can use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). To get a different starting point for each CustID you can use [MIN()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with an [OVER clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Aggregate functions can be used with an `OVER` close that restricts the range they apply to:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CustID) OVER (PARTITION BY CustID)
        + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CustId,Number)
    AS SeqNo,
    MyTable.*
FROM MyTable CROSS join Numbers 
WHERE  TotalCount < Numbers.Number
```

Answer (score 0):

@seanb @pana

for the total count, i will get the min and max custid from my table

```
CREATE TABLE #n (n int);
declare @start int, @end int
select @start= min(rk) from MyTable
select @end= max(rk) from MyTable
while @start <=@end
begin 
INSERT INTO #n (n) VALUES (@start)
set @start=@start+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select CustID, EmpID, TotalCount, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select CustID, EmpID, TotalCount, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < TotalCount
     )
select (CustId + n - 1) as seqno, CustID, EmpID, TotalCount
from cte;
```

If you needed to add more than 100 rows, you would need `option (maxrecursion 0)` as the last line in the query.